# Best way to share collection with customer

Tags: mongodb, rest, security

Recently we are working with a customer who want's one of our mongodb collection to be shared with them. I'm pretty new to Dev/Sys Ops so I'm wondering what would be the best way to share collection with them?

Client needs to be able to specify dates and then pull all of the data in that range from collection (so some sort of query is needed).

I was considering giving them access to mongo through ssh, but would that be secure and appropiate?

Second thing I consider was by creating some simple webapp and then sending it over as POST

Thoughts? Cheers

Comment: Why not create a simple web app to query mongo to act as an abstraction layer... I wouldn't give them access to the entire database - though that depends on your relationship and what else is on the Mongo instance.

Comment: Hey, yeah we don't want to expose entire database. Ok, so I'd create a simple web app where they'd select from and to date and what format would that be returned in? as POST parameters or print on the web? Our client wants it for they dev work to create some reports etc

Comment: A simple REST API should suffice - sending the search criteria to your API, then querying MongoDB.Returning in JSON format would be easier - though this depends on your customers requirements.

Comment: Sounds like a plan - thanks a lot!

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ you should post that as an answer - it's probably the best solution.

Comment: @vincebowdren ah you're right - [Best way to share collection with customer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36039508/3000179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I have ended up simply creating username and password to mongo to my client and set correct permissions leaving them with doing all the heavy lifting.

Comment: So is there no data that your client needs abstracting from? You should also mention that you share 100% of data with a 3rd party.

Comment: I have created collection with all the necessary data my client required and gave them access to read this collection - and this collection only

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Posting my comment as an answer after a small discussion with OP*</sup>

A simple [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) should suffice - sending the search criteria to your API, then querying MongoDB.

Returning in JSON format would be easier - though this depends on your customers requirements.